# exception occurred when reset region center in a iOS6 map

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit

I encountered this exception when I reset the center region of the map:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'Invalid Region <center:+118.11638600, +24.50967900 span:+0.04486573, -0.09506065>'
```

I set region use below method:

```
MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(_location, _searchRadius, _searchRadius);
```

`_location` , `searchRadius` as I can see by NSlog, were `{118.116386 24.509679}, 5000`.

so what is the cause of this exception ? any advise? thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess, your radius is making a region that is bigger than the map of the world in one of the directions. try starting from a small region and working out until you get this error again.

Comment: Is your center lat/long valid?

Try validating it if this certain set of lat/long gives you back a valid location or not:
http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html

Comment: I tried as you said,but still not working. only this time, I tried another way to make a region,                        MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(_location, MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1));                                           still crashed and reported to me it was an invalid region

Comment: Are you sure that it is this region that is crashing it?

Comment: turned out it's because the center lat/long invalid,fixed by input with valid ones.Thanks guys.